How do you solve an integral with terms to the right of the differential?
I’ve been reading Fundamentals of Aerodynamics by J. D. Anderson and came across this integral:
$$\iint_S(\rho\cdot\vec{V}\bullet d\vec{S})\cdot\vec{V}$$
It represents the net flow of momentum out of the control volume through S. I understand how the physics that this integral represents works. But I have a few questions about the math of the integral:

What I don’t understand is how you would go about solving such an integral. What confuses me the most is that the second velocity vector, $\vec{V}$, is to the right of the differential, $d\vec{S}$. Is this even legal?
Also, when the author of the textbook converts the momentum expression from integral form to differential form using the divergence theorem:
$$x\text{-component}: \iint_S(\rho\cdot\vec{V}\bullet d\vec{S})\cdot u=\iint_S(\rho\cdot\ u\cdot\vec{V}\bullet d\vec{S})=\iiint_{V\llap{—}}\vec{\nabla}\bullet(\rho\cdot u \cdot\vec{V}) \,d V\llap{—}$$
Here the assumption is that the control volume, $V\llap{—}$, is infinitesimally small. My questions is: are we allowed to bring $u$ inside the integrand because $u$ is basically uniform in the infinitesimally small control volume?


What is $u$? Are you sure that $u$ isn't part of the integrand already in the first integral?

$u$ is x component of the velocity vector, $\vec{V}$. There are two more similar parts from this integral for the other two components.

If you think of $d\vec S$ as $(dx,dy,dz)$ or whatever kind of expression is appropriate, then you just expand out the vector notation until you get a vector of scalar integrals. That's really all this notation means fundamentally. In the same fashion, if you have arbitrary $L_{\vec r}(\vec v)$ linear in $\vec v$ with $\vec r\in S$ then you can make sense of $\iint_SL_{\vec r}(d\vec S)$ with $\vec r$ the variable of integration.
